# Display Java GUI label from inside another function

Tags: java, user-interface

Read comments in code...

```
public GUI() {
    // make the GUI
}

private class theHandler implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        // if they clicked a button then do main1
    }
}

public static void main1(String string) throws IOException {
    // random code
    add(labelThatIWantToShow); // I want to display the label I created in GUI()
}
```

-- If you didn't understand the comments --

I want to display a label outside where I created the GUI. I know there is an obvious answer to this I just can't think of it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to provide some context to the code that wants to add a label, for example:

```
public static void main1(GUI gui, String string)
{
}
```

... otherwise there's no way of knowing which window you want to add the label to.

You *could* potentially use a static variable to hold "the single window that's been created" but I'd advise against this - global state makes it hard to reason about the code.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get [low coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) between you components (which are the GUI and the "main code" in your case) you could make use of the idea which is known as "Publish/Suscribe" or [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Doing so you can easily change your whole GUI without altering your main code. You would gain a better encapsulation of the single aspects of your code (*displaying* results to the user and *computing* them) and you would especially be able to solve your current problem.

Simple example code:

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;


public class GUIExample implements Observer {

    private String state = "foo";

    public GUIExample() {
        System.out.println("GUI created");
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        this.state = "bar";
        System.out.println("GUI updated: " + state);
    }


}
```

And your main code:

```
import java.util.Observable;


public class MainCode extends Observable {

    // you could call doStuff() if some certain action was performed
    public void doStuff() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainCode mc = new MainCode(); 
        mc.addObserver(new GUIExample());
        mc.doStuff();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be to remove the `static` qualifier from your `main1` method. Of course, I'm assuming that `add(labelThatIWantToShow);` is not the actual code; you'll have to use the correct code for whichever GUI toolkit you're using.

The other way -- if you can't get rid of `static` for some reason -- would be to do what Jon proposed and pass an argument to `main1`.

Comment: Thanks, however I can't remove the static qualifier.